# GUI Input with select.select() in Python

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

When using the `select.select()` method in Python, is there any way to use input from a GUI (Tkinter Entry) to send data out of a socket?

The input list of select() accepts sys.stdin or received data from a server, but is there anyway to get data from a GUI and have it be sent out? Or is select not usable with a GUI?

I have searched extensively, but if you have a link to another thread I'd appreciate that as well.

```
import socket, select, threading, Queue, cPickle
from Tkinter import *
from Message import *

class GUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, host="localhost",port=5678, root="Tk()"):
        Frame.__init__(self,root)
        self.nickname = raw_input("What is your screen name? ")
        self.inqueue = Queue.Queue()
        self.outqueue = Queue.Queue()
        self.root = root
        self.text = Text(self,height=10,width=40)
        self.scroll=Scrollbar(self)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
        self.scroll.config(command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.pack()
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))
        self.sock.send(self.nickname)
        self.thread1=threading.Thread(target=self.cmdloop)
        self.thread1.start()
        self.entry.bind("<Return>",self.enter)
        self.call()

    def enter(self,event):
        msg = Message(self.nickname,0,self.entry.get())
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
        msg = cPickle.dumps(msg)
        self.inqueue.put(msg)
        self.sock.send(msg)

    def call(self):
        self.processData()
        self.after(100,self.call)

    def cmdloop(self):
        while 1:
            sys.stdout.flush()
            # Wait for input from stdin & socket
            inputs, outputs, excepts = select.select([0,self.sock],[],[])

            for i in inputs:
                if i == 0:
                    data = sys.stdin.readline()
                    msg = Message(self.nickname,0,data)
                    msg = cPickle.dumps(msg)
                    self.inqueue.put(msg)
                    self.sock.send(msg)

                elif i == self.sock:
                    data = self.sock.recv(1024)
                    self.inqueue.put(data)

    def processData(self):
        while self.inqueue.qsize():
            try:
                msg = self.inqueue.get(0)
                msg = cPickle.loads(msg) 
                self.text.insert(END, msg.getusr()+": "+msg.getmsg())
                self.text.yview(END)
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("textarea")
    client = GUI(sys.argv[1],int(sys.argv[2]),root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `select.select()` has nothing to do with directly sending or receiving data.

Comment: I have tried many things. In this I tried putting my outcode in a queue for the writable sockets. That doesn't work. I tried sending it directly from my enter() method, and that doesn't work either. Am I stuck in the cmdloop()? I have no way to send data from the GUI through the socket. If the select function has the sys.stdin as an option, I can send stuff from the terminal just fine with readline() but otherwise I cannot figure this out.

Comment: Dewzy, can you trim down your program to a minimal example that shows what's not working? Also, what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was asking the question poorly, thank you to those who tried to answer despite my poor phrasing. I had just started using Python. Either way, here is an answer my group member found to the question I was *trying* to ask. I do not know if he wrote it himself or found it on a website, but it is basically just a use of the TKinter `after()` call.

Our main loop looks like:

```
def cmdloop():
    (sread, swrite, sexc) = select.select( [sock], [], [], 0)
    for s in sread:
        ...
        ...
        ...
    app.after(500,cmdloop)
```

That half second break allowed the textbox call `inputBox.bind('<Return>', sendMsg)` (and the message waiting to send in the socket) to work properly. `sendMsg()` then simply had a `sock.send()` call.

```
def sendMsg(event=''):
    message = inputBox.get()
    message += "\n"
    msg = Message(nickname,0,message,None) #Custom Class
    sock.send(pickle.dumps(msg))
    inputBox.delete(0,END)
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Select() and the GUI are completely unrelated. You can get text from a GUI widget, and  you can send text through a socket, therefore you can get text from a GUI and send it over a socket like any other string.

Are you aware that both the entry widget and text widget have a `get` method to fetch the text? Have you tried fetching the text and then sending it just like you would if you had called `readline` instead of `self.text.get`?

Comment: Okay, I cleaned up the code. Here is my dilemma. With this code, if I enter stuff into the terminal, it works fine. The GUI shows the code, the server we have receives it. However, if I try to type anything into the entry and hit enter, nothing happens. I can still type to the terminal, and that still sends to the server, but nothing happens with the Tkinter Entry.

I can't add the Tkinter Entry field into `select` because its not a socket or a file-like object with a `fileno` method.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind actions to both entry modification, stdin or a socket, there is simpler way that does not event use thread. The idea is to bind actions to filehandlers through Tkinter instead of trying to provide your own mainloop with select and retrieve Tkinter events.

You can rely on Tkinter mainloop to bind functions to file descriptor events through `createfilehandler(fd,mask,callback)`, for instance `root.createfilehandler(sys.stdin,READABLE,callback)`.

Here is a demo appplication

```
from Tkinter import *
import socket

master = Tk()

entry = Entry(master)
entry.pack()

def process(data):
    print "processing: {0}".format(data)

def stdin_callback(fd, mask):
    print "stdin"
    data = sys.stdin.readline()
    process(data[:-1])

def socket_callback(fd, mask):
    print "socket"
    try:
        data= sock.recv(1024)
        if data:
            process (data)
        else:
            close_socket ()
    except socket.error as ex:
        close_socket ()

def close_socket():
    #closing socket without removing filehandler may hurt
    sock.close()
    master.deletefilehandler(fileno)

def entry_callback(event):
    print "entry"
    process(event.widget.get())

entry.bind("<Return>", entry_callback)
master.createfilehandler(sys.stdin,READABLE, stdin_callback)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("localhost", 5678))
fileno = sock.fileno()
master.createfilehandler(fileno, READABLE, socket_callback)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: fwiw, this won't work on windows as it lacks `createfilehandler`.